# Problem with dialog within another dialog

Tags: android, recursion, dialog, progressdialog

While dowloading data i display a progressdialog with a cancel button. If pressed an alertDialog pops open for verification. If ascertained, the download is cancelled and both dialog disappear. But if the user negates the cancel, ALSO both dialogs diappear. Which is very bad, because it misleads the user into assuming the download is finished. What I want, is that the progressDialog remains on the screen until the download really is finished. Any ideas?

Here is the code I used:

```
ProgressDialog makeProgressDialog() {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("downloading, please wait...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  
        { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)  
        { 
            new AlertDialog.Builder(TUIActivity.this)
            .setMessage("Sure?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // cancel the download
                        }
                    }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("No", new EmptyListener())
            .show();

        } 
    }); 
    return progressDialog;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution: don't use a `ProgressDialog`. Use the progress indicator in the title bar, or a `ProgressBar`, or some other indicator that you are doing work.